# Can't send request to docker container in nextjs getStaticProps?

Tags: javascript, docker, api, docker-compose, next.js

I'm trying to send a simple GET request from my Next.js `getStaticProps` function to another container which is a node backend api using docker-compose.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/home/node/app/
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/home/node/app/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - "web"
```

Index.js in Next.js:

```js
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const { data } = await axios({ method: "GET", url: "http://web:3001" })

  return {
    props: {
      data: data.message,
    },
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I connected my other non Next.js apps with the same url `http://web:3001` and they work just fine. why can't I build my next.js app?

Comment: You should define a network that is shared between all your containers, so you can access the backend on web:3001.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: The front-end application runs in your browser; that's outside of Docker space and it can't use any of the Docker networking features.  It has to connect to the published `ports:` of the backend container; if the browser and containers are all running on the same host, `http://localhost:3001`.

Comment: but the getStaticProps function is run server side